# Unable to setup IDP token exchange in Keycloak 4.6.0.Final

Tags: jboss, keycloak

After spinning up a Keycloak instance by [docker image 4.6.0.Final](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/), the permissions tab of the client and Identity Providers are missing. The tabs are available in version 4.5.0.Final out of the box. The missing of permission tab prevents the setup of token exchange by following official document, [Securing Apps Token Exchange](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_token-exchange)

Comment: I have the same problem, I will send an email to user mailing group.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have received an answer from Pedro Silva via the mailing list:

Hi,

...We no longer enable tech preview features by default. You need to enable the feature you want, such as admin fine grained permissions, by passing a specific environment variable. Try to boot your server using this system property:

```
-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.admin_fine_grained_authz=enabled
-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.token_exchange=enabled
```

Docs are not reflecting these changes, created https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-8865.

Comment: Yes, the permission tabs are back after specifying the system property by env `-e 'JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.admin_fine_grained_authz=enabled -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.token_exchange=enabled' ` to docker run command.

Comment: And to enable the script Authentication feature, add `-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.scripts=enabled`